# Drools In Spark for Streaming File

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming, drools

We were able to successfully Integrate drools with spark, When we try to apply rules from Drools we were able to do for Batch file, which is present in HDFS, But we tried to use drools for Streaming file so that we can make decision instantly, But we couldn't figure out how to do it.Below is the snippet of the code what we are trying to achieve.
**Case1:** .

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sample");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<String> javaRDD = sc.textFile("/user/root/spark/sample.dat");
    List<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();
    store = javaRDD.collect();
```

***Case 2:***  when we use streaming context

```
SparkConf sparkconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sparkstreaming");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = 
              new JavaStreamingContext(sparkconf, new Duration(1));

    JavaDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream("xx.xx.xx.xx", xxxx);
```

*In the first case we were able apply our rules on the variable store, but in the second case we were not able to apply rules on the `dstream` lines.*

If someone has some idea, how it can be done, will be a great help.

Comment: for example i have given user/root/, original will be user/vish/spark/sample.dat

Comment: Did @krishna-gajula 's answer work?

Comment: Did the answer below worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get it done.

1. Create your knowledge session with business rules first.

   ```
   //Create knowledge and session here
   KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
   KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
   kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newFileResource( "rulefile.drl"),
           ResourceType.DRL );
   Collection<KnowledgePackage> pkgs = kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages();
   kbase.addKnowledgePackages( pkgs );
   final StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
   ```
2. Create JavaDStream using StreamingContext.

   ```
   SparkConf sparkconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sparkstreaming");
   JavaStreamingContext ssc = 
             new JavaStreamingContext(sparkconf, new Duration(1));
   JavaDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream("xx.xx.xx.xx", xxxx);
   ```
3. Call DStream's foreachRDD to create facts and fire your rules.

   ```
   lines.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
     @Override
     public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
        List<String> facts = rdd.collect();
        //Apply rules on facts here
        ksession.execute(facts);
        return null;
     }
   });
   ```